# In Lean 4 how to substitute equals in an expression with other variables?

Tags: lean4, beginner, substitution

I can use 'subst' to prove that if a=b and a is positive then b is positive:

`example (a b : Peano) (h1 : a = b) (h2 : pos a) : pos b := Eq.subst h1 h2`

How do I prove that if a=b and a > c then b > c:

`example (a b c: Peano) (h1 : a = b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c := Eq.subst h1 h2 -- does not work`

Note that I am learning Lean 4 by using my own 'Peano' natural numbers, so I only want a solution that uses non-numeric tactics (i.e. propositional logic and equality). It appears that 'congr' or 'congrArg' may help (do I need to specify a lambda expression?) but I have not succeeded.

Comment: Note, Lean isn't based on propositional logic or first-order logic, so some things which you would consider pure logical rules in first-order logic, like substitution, are actually theorems proved in Lean via induction on the definition of equality.  At the heart of Lean is the `rec` recursor.   Then `match`, `induction`, etc are built on top of that to make case analysis and induction easier.  For equality specifically, the ▸ macro, `rewrite` tactic. and `calc` proofs are designed to make it easy for users. And then there is even more powerful automation like the `simp` tactic on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [the ▸ macro](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/quantifiers_and_equality.html#equality), which you can write using `\t` in VSCode.

```
-- definitions of Peano and gt don't matter here
axiom Peano : Type  
axiom gt (a b : Peano): Prop

example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : a = b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c :=
  h1 ▸ h2
```

The macro is quite flexible and can be used in a number of situations where you want to do substitution using an equality.

As for the more direct approach, I'm not sure why `Eq.subst h1 h2` doesn't work, but if you fill in all the implicit arguments it works:

```
example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : a = b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c :=
  @Eq.subst Peano (fun x => gt x c) a b h1 h2
```

If you are fine with the `rewrite` tactic (which is a purely logical tactic), then that works well also:

```
example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : a = b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c := by
  rewrite [<- h1]
  exact h2
```

---

As for learning how equality actually works in Lean, I highly recommend you read the [Equality section in Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/quantifiers_and_equality.html#equality).

In particular, [equality is defined inductively](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/b614ff1d12bc38f39077f9ce9f2d48b42c003ad0/src/Init/Prelude.lean#L276-L279) (just like the natural numbers) with one constructor `refl`.  You can even define your own version:

```
inductive MyEq : α → α → Prop where
  | refl (a : α) : MyEq a a
```

Since it is an inductive, we can use induction (sometimes called "path induction"):

```
example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : MyEq a b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c := by 
  induction h1
  exact h2
```

The idea is that if we can construct or prove `P a` and we have `MyEq a b`, then we can construct or prove `P b` as well.

This is also easy to write as a case analysis using the single `refl` constructor for `MyEq`.

```
example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : MyEq a b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c :=
  match h1 with
  | MyEq.refl a => h2
```

Finally, if you really want to get to the very inner guts of Lean, you can directly use the `rec` recursor (which I don't recommend for actual Lean code, but in this case, it is really simple to use).

```
example (a b c : Peano) (h1 : MyEq a b) (h2 : gt a c) : gt b c :=
  MyEq.rec h2 h1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed and extremely helpful answers! I used the simple "rw [h]; exact" to finally prove:  x > y  ∧  pos z  →  x * z > y * z (together with some previously proved theorems).